# Spark - Efficient key partitioning, can you combine partition methods?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a parquet file in HDFS, about 1tb in size. Currently the data is partitioned by the default method (not sure what this is - I previously thought it was hash partitioned) but the next step needs to join rows against each other using a "guid" column so I am hunting for the optimal partitioning implementation. My current definition of inefficiency is there is substantial shuffling of the dataset to do the mentioned join, and there are about 79k files in the parquet dir for the 1tb, about 13mb per partition. A repartion could be an easy initial win (I inherited this dataset - didn't set it up) but I think some form of guid partition would be better given my current knowledge of how partitioning works

My understanding of what makes a good partition:

- Data should be partitioned on a column key that will be used for further aggregations to minimize shuffling
- The partition size should be around 128mb, as it seems to be widely considered a "sweet spot" size

The data is timeseries, so partitioning by date is a good start but I need to partition within that for later operations (using guid). I was thinking of partitioning by date and also a rangePartitioner on the guid.

My questions:

1. Is this even possible? I am setting up the rangePartition now but I can see no instances online of combining partitionByKey of a column and a rangePartitioner?
2. The guids will not make for an even partition. Some will have more rows than others. I am hoping the rangePartitioner will help this somewhat but there is no guarantee. Is there anything that will dynamically partition across a key to balance partition sizes as best it can? I am aiming for 128mb per partition so have to use some heuristics/estimations to get as close as possible at the moment.
3. Finally - If/when I append more data to the partitioned file will that data follow the same partitioning methodology?

Example of table:

```
//============[]======[]===========[]====================\\
||    Date    || Guid || SubGuidID || Misc Other columns ||
|]============[]======[]===========[]====================[|
|| 2018-04-30 ||    1 ||         1 || x                  ||
|| 2018-04-30 ||    1 ||         2 || y                  ||
|| 2018-04-30 ||    2 ||         1 || z                  ||
\\============[]======[]===========[]====================//
```

Comment: _Currently the data is hash partitioned but it is proving quite inefficient_ - data on disk is definitely not hash partitioned. It might clustered (bucketed), which would be used for optimization, or might be partitioned, which wouldn't be. Could [edit] your question, and be more specific? Also, it might be useful if you explain why you think that `RangePartitionier` is worth the shot -  it might behave in some  border cases (and more with `RDDs` than `Datasets`), but definitely not in a general case.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the query plans that back up the claim _"it is proving quite inefficient for joins"_. What exactly is the inefficiency? What queries are you trying to optimize?

Comment: I have added some more information into the post, I seem to have misunderstood default partitioning!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.